# open file with full project path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This should not be too hard: I've got the path of a file relative to my project root (e.g. copied from the console: src/main/java/org/hello/World.java) and want to open this file in eclipse. I can't find how to do this.

I can open a resource and give it "world.java", but I might have many world.java files and I already have the full path in my clipboard so why start searching again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd> and put `*/` in front of the path (i.e. type <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>)